# Displaying contacts in android listview

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, contactscontract

Here i am using the below code to display contacts in my application.It is displaying only one contact.the contact which is there in the last position is displayed..How to display all contacts..can anyone tell me how to display all the contacts.?I have used print statement in getNumber() method..the contacts are displayed in log as print statement..but not in device.

```
public class ContactsDisplay extends AppCompatActivity implements  OnItemClickListener,FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    private static String TAG = ContactsDisplay.class.getSimpleName();

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

    String phoneNumber;
    String name;
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList <String> aa= new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        setContentView(R.layout.contacts_display);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

        // display the second navigation drawer view on app launch
        displayView(0);

        lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

       // getNumber(this.getContentResolver());
        getNumber();
    }

    public void getNumber()
    {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            int contactIdIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID);
            int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
            int phoneNumberIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            int photoIdIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_ID);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                String idContact = cursor.getString(contactIdIdx);
                String name = cursor.getString(nameIdx);
                String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneNumberIdx);
                aa.add(name+"\n"+phoneNumber);

                System.out.println(".................."+phoneNumber);
                System.out.println(".................." + name);
                //...
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            cursor.close();// close cursor
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,aa);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {

        Intent intent;

        switch (position) {

            default:
                intent = new Intent(ContactsDisplay.this, Banking.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if(id == R.id.action_search){
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), vault_no, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
           // logout();
        }

        if(id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        displayView(position);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                /*fragment = new HomeFragment();*/
                title = "Work Details1";

                break;

            case 1:
                /*fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_profile);
                break;*/
                startActivity(new Intent(this, ContactsDisplay.class));
                return;
            case 2:

                startActivity(new Intent (this,Events.class));
                return;
                /*fragment = new AboutFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_about);
                break;*/
            case 3:
                fragment = new MessagesFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_messages);
                break;

            case 4:
                fragment = new VideoFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_video);
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new GalleryFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_gallery);
                break;
            case 6:
                fragment = new GalleryFragment();
                title = "Gallery";
                break;

            case 7:
                fragment = new EventsFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_events);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            // set the toolbar title
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you code seem right,you should debug the code between do-while，and watching the log

Comment: In log it is showing like this..`06-16 06:48:48.495 19357-19357/com.example.miisky I/System.out: ..................(934) 134-0660
06-16 06:48:48.495 19357-19357/com.example.miisky I/System.out: ..................sachin
06-16 06:48:48.503 19357-19357/com.example.miisky I/System.out: ..................(996) 656-0754
06-16 06:48:48.503 19357-19357/com.example.miisky I/System.out: ..................prajwal`